Getting issue while integrating google mediapipe in flutter
I am trying to integrate MediaPipe Poselandmarker in my flutter app using native communication with the help of method channel. The problem is when the camera is getting opened,it is being displayed over top of overlay. But i want overlay to be displayed over top of camera. I am sharing my kotlin code for reference. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.
This is my NativeView.kt:, In this I am setting up fragment container
 private fun setupFragmentContainer(context: Context) {
        Log.d("NativeView", "Setting up FragmentContainerView for CameraFragment")

        // Create a FragmentContainerView dynamically if not already added.
        val fragmentContainerView = FragmentContainerView(context).apply {
            id = View.generateViewId() // Generate a unique ID for the container
            layoutParams = LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        }
        this.addView(fragmentContainerView)

        // Use FragmentManager to add or replace the fragment
        val fragmentActivity = activity as? FragmentActivity ?: throw ClassCastException("Activity must be a FragmentActivity")

        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        // Check if CameraFragment is already added
        val existingFragment = fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("CameraFragment")

        if (existingFragment == null) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainerView.id, CameraFragment(), "CameraFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
            Log.d("NativeView", "CameraFragment added to FragmentContainerView")
        } else {
            Log.d("NativeView", "CameraFragment already exists, no need to add again")
        }

        // After fragment is added, bring overlays to the front
//        val overlayView = findViewById<OverlayView>(R.id.overlay) // Ensure this ID is correct
//        overlayView.bringToFront()
//
//        val bottomSheetLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout)
//        bottomSheetLayout.bringToFront()
//
//        // Optionally, invalidate the views to make sure they get redrawn
//        overlayView.invalidate()
//        bottomSheetLayout.invalidate()

    }

This is my CameraFragmemt.kt
/*
 * Copyright 2023 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package app.peak.med.bibo.fragment

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.core.Camera
import androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import app.peak.med.bibo.PoseLandmarkerHelper
import app.peak.med.bibo.MainViewModel
import app.peak.med.bibo.OverlayView
import app.peak.med.bibo.R
import app.peak.med.bibo.databinding.FragmentCameraBinding
import com.google.mediapipe.tasks.vision.core.RunningMode
import java.util.Locale
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class CameraFragment : Fragment(), PoseLandmarkerHelper.LandmarkerListener {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CAMERA FRAGMENT"
    }

    private var _fragmentCameraBinding: FragmentCameraBinding? = null

    private val fragmentCameraBinding
        get() = _fragmentCameraBinding!!

    private lateinit var poseLandmarkerHelper: PoseLandmarkerHelper
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private var cameraFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT

    /** Blocking ML operations are performed using this executor */
    private lateinit var backgroundExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Make sure that all permissions are still present, since the
        // user could have removed them while the app was in paused state.
        if (!PermissionsFragment.hasPermissions(requireContext())) {
            Navigation.findNavController(
                requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container
            ).navigate(R.id.action_camera_to_permissions)
        }

        // Start the PoseLandmarkerHelper again when users come back
        // to the foreground.
        backgroundExecutor.execute {
            if(this::poseLandmarkerHelper.isInitialized) {
                if (poseLandmarkerHelper.isClose()) {
                    poseLandmarkerHelper.setupPoseLandmarker()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if(this::poseLandmarkerHelper.isInitialized) {
            viewModel.setMinPoseDetectionConfidence(poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence)
            viewModel.setMinPoseTrackingConfidence(poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence)
            viewModel.setMinPosePresenceConfidence(poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence)
            viewModel.setDelegate(poseLandmarkerHelper.currentDelegate)

            // Close the PoseLandmarkerHelper and release resources
            backgroundExecutor.execute { poseLandmarkerHelper.clearPoseLandmarker() }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _fragmentCameraBinding = null
        super.onDestroyView()

        // Shut down our background executor
        backgroundExecutor.shutdown()
        backgroundExecutor.awaitTermination(
            Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _fragmentCameraBinding =
            FragmentCameraBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return fragmentCameraBinding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val overlayView = view.findViewById<OverlayView>(R.id.overlay)
        overlayView.bringToFront()
        // If needed, ensure bottom sheet layout is on top of both camera and overlay
//        val bottomSheetLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout)
//        bottomSheetLayout.bringToFront()
        view.requestLayout()
        // Initialize our background executor
        backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        // Wait for the views to be properly laid out
        fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.post {
            // Set up the camera and its use cases
            setUpCamera()
            overlayView.bringToFront()
            //fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.bringToFront() // Ensure overlay is above camera view.
        }

        // Create the PoseLandmarkerHelper that will handle the inference
        backgroundExecutor.execute {
            poseLandmarkerHelper = PoseLandmarkerHelper(
                context = requireContext(),
                runningMode = RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
                minPoseDetectionConfidence = viewModel.currentMinPoseDetectionConfidence,
                minPoseTrackingConfidence = viewModel.currentMinPoseTrackingConfidence,
                minPosePresenceConfidence = viewModel.currentMinPosePresenceConfidence,
                currentDelegate = viewModel.currentDelegate,
                poseLandmarkerHelperListener = this
            )
        }

        // Attach listeners to UI control widgets
       // initBottomSheetControls()
    }

    /*private fun initBottomSheetControls() {
        // init bottom sheet settings

        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.detectionThresholdValue.text =
            String.format(
                Locale.US, "%.2f", viewModel.currentMinPoseDetectionConfidence
            )
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.trackingThresholdValue.text =
            String.format(
                Locale.US, "%.2f", viewModel.currentMinPoseTrackingConfidence
            )
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.presenceThresholdValue.text =
            String.format(
                Locale.US, "%.2f", viewModel.currentMinPosePresenceConfidence
            )

        // When clicked, lower pose detection score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.detectionThresholdMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence >= 0.2) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence -= 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, raise pose detection score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.detectionThresholdPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence <= 0.8) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence += 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, lower pose tracking score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.trackingThresholdMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence >= 0.2) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence -= 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, raise pose tracking score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.trackingThresholdPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence <= 0.8) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence += 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, lower pose presence score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.presenceThresholdMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence >= 0.2) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence -= 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, raise pose presence score threshold floor
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.presenceThresholdPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence <= 0.8) {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence += 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, change the underlying hardware used for inference.
        // Current options are CPU and GPU
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerDelegate.setSelection(
            viewModel.currentDelegate, false
        )
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerDelegate.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long
                ) {
                    try {
                        poseLandmarkerHelper.currentDelegate = p2
                        updateControlsUi()
                    } catch(e: UninitializedPropertyAccessException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "PoseLandmarkerHelper has not been initialized yet.")
                    }
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    /* no op */
                }
            }

        // When clicked, change the underlying model used for object detection
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerModel.setSelection(
            viewModel.currentModel,
            false
        )
        fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerModel.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    p0: AdapterView<*>?,
                    p1: View?,
                    p2: Int,
                    p3: Long
                ) {
                    poseLandmarkerHelper.currentModel = p2
                    updateControlsUi()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    /* no op */
                }
            }
    }*/

    // Update the values displayed in the bottom sheet. Reset Poselandmarker
    // helper.
    /*private fun updateControlsUi() {
        if(this::poseLandmarkerHelper.isInitialized) {
            fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.detectionThresholdValue.text =
                String.format(
                    Locale.US,
                    "%.2f",
                    poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseDetectionConfidence
                )
            fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.trackingThresholdValue.text =
                String.format(
                    Locale.US,
                    "%.2f",
                    poseLandmarkerHelper.minPoseTrackingConfidence
                )
            fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.presenceThresholdValue.text =
                String.format(
                    Locale.US,
                    "%.2f",
                    poseLandmarkerHelper.minPosePresenceConfidence
                )

            // Needs to be cleared instead of reinitialized because the GPU
            // delegate needs to be initialized on the thread using it when applicable
            backgroundExecutor.execute {
                poseLandmarkerHelper.clearPoseLandmarker()
                poseLandmarkerHelper.setupPoseLandmarker()
            }
            fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.clear()
        }
    }*/

    // Initialize CameraX, and prepare to bind the camera use cases
    private fun setUpCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture =
            ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
            {
                // CameraProvider
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                // Build and bind the camera use cases
                bindCameraUseCases()
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
        )
    }

    // Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // CameraProvider
        val cameraProvider = cameraProvider
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        val cameraSelector =
            CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(cameraFacing).build()

        // Preview. Only using the 4:3 ratio because this is the closest to our models
        preview = Preview.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
            .build()

        // ImageAnalysis. Using RGBA 8888 to match how our models work
        imageAnalyzer =
            ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                .build()
                // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(backgroundExecutor) { image ->
                        detectPose(image)
                    }
                }

        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer
            )

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
//            val overlayView: View = view.findViewById(R.id.overlay) // This can be any view like lines or annotations
//            overlayView.bringToFront()
            val overlayView: View? = view?.findViewById(R.id.overlay)!!
            overlayView?.let {
                // Do something with the overlay view, e.g., bring it to the front
                it.bringToFront()
            }
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }

    private fun detectPose(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        if(this::poseLandmarkerHelper.isInitialized) {
            poseLandmarkerHelper.detectLiveStream(
                imageProxy = imageProxy,
                isFrontCamera = cameraFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        imageAnalyzer?.targetRotation =
            fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation
    }

    // Update UI after pose have been detected. Extracts original
    // image height/width to scale and place the landmarks properly through
    // OverlayView
    override fun onResults(
        resultBundle: PoseLandmarkerHelper.ResultBundle
    ) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            if (_fragmentCameraBinding != null) {
//                fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text =
//                    String.format("%d ms", resultBundle.inferenceTime)
                //fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.bringToFront()
                // Pass necessary information to OverlayView for drawing on the canvas
                fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.setResults(
                    resultBundle.results.first(),
                    resultBundle.inputImageHeight,
                    resultBundle.inputImageWidth,
                    RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM
                )

                // Force a redraw
                fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onError(error: String, errorCode: Int) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if (errorCode == PoseLandmarkerHelper.GPU_ERROR) {
               // fragmentCameraBinding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerDelegate.setSelection(
                //    PoseLandmarkerHelper.DELEGATE_CPU, false
                //)
            }
        }
    }
}


In MainActivity.kt, when I am running the below code, overlay is getting built on top of camera
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        activityMainBinding.navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
        activityMainBinding.navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            // ignore the reselection
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }
}

But when I have changed it to flutterFragmentActivity, above problem is coming
class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {
//class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
companion object {
    private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // No need to access flutterEngine here; it will be configured below.
}

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    try {
        flutterEngine.plugins.add(FlutterMediapipePlugin())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_mediapipe", e)
    }
}

}
